# Flutter Grpc: Unable to connect to server

Tags: flutter, dart, networking, grpc

I'm building a flutter app on Windows (Android Studio). The backend is a Rust(tonic) Grpc server running on WSL2. However, I'm having troubles connecting to the server from my app. I've tried as many solutions as I can find online or think about. The error is usually something like this:

```bash
connection refused (os error: connection refused, errno = 111), address = localhost, port = 49450
```

```dart
// client.dart
final grpcChannel = ClientChannel(
  // '10.0.2.2',
  'localhost' // adding my ipv4 doesn't work either,
  port: 50051,
  options: const ChannelOptions(credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure())
);
```

- I have disabled firewalls from windows.
- I have tried to use all the IPv4s I can find using `ipconfig`.
- I have tried with Android Emulator and a real android device.
- I have tried using ngrok with something like `grpc://ngrok_url`.

But the issue persists. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**PLEASE NOTE**: Grpc Server works when tested from postman (using localhost). It also works if I run the client code directly from terminal (also using localhost). It doesn't work on both if I use my IP instead. This is an example code I run from the terminal:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  try {
    final stub = AuthClient(grpcChannel);
    RegisterRequest data = RegisterRequest();
    
    var resp = await stub.register(data);
    print("message received: ${resp.status}");

  } catch(e){
    print("error received: $e");
  }

}
```

I only have connection issues when I try to connect from my Flutter app.

I have disabled firewalls from windows.
I have tried to use all the IPv4s I can find using `ipconfig`.
I have tried with Android Emulator and a real android device.
I have tried using ngrok with something like `grpc://ngrok_url`.